# JDBC: Catch "SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset caused" by "SocketException: Connection reset"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

My code establishes JDBC connection and repeatedly queries Microsoft SQL SMS. However, sometimes I get the error:

> **"Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset"** followed by **"Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"**
>   [image]

Here is what my code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    // Establish JDBC connection
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
    ...
    // Perform SQL query
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        functionA(stmt); // <--line 62
    ...
}

public static void functionA(Statement stmt){
    String aql = "INSERT INTO...";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql); // <-- line 105
}
```

I query the database in order to test some function unrelated to the data. Hence, I want my program to automatically re-establish the connection when the exception is thrown so I can leave it running by itself.

**My questions are:
1)Can I re-establish JDBC connection in try...catch? 2)If so, which exception to catch and where to catch it? 3)What should I place in catch?**

Comment: Which part of  your program "repeatedly queries" the database ?

Comment: It is a for-loop which wraps around functionA.

Comment: Please include exception stacktraces as text and not as screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you want to catch the exception that you listed in the question, you will need to catch the SQLException, for example :

```
  // Perform SQL query
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        try {
        functionA(stmt); // <--line 62
        } catch(SQLException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          //You can add here your recovery logic ...
        }
    }
```

And yes, you can try to reestablish the connection after the exception putting in place a kind of reconnect mechanism in the catch block ...

In the case you want to check the inner exception that caused the SQLException you can check the that with getCause() :

```
        } catch(SQLException e) {
          if(e.getCause() instanceof SocketException) {
          //You can add here your recovery logic ...
          }
        }
```

Comment: Wasn't SocketException the "cause" of SQLException according to the error message? And do you know I may re-establish connection?

Comment: yes, you can even check the inner exception if you want... It depends on what you need to do ...

Comment: I'd like my program to not stop and re-establish connection. Any fix leads to that is fine with me.

Comment: You can put a recovery logic inside the catch block and if the recovery is successful, then you can go ahead ...